# Is there GSON java libraries feature of providing alternative value for key present in swift Codable?

Tags: android, swift, codable, decodable

I came across an API where I have to reuse one of my existing Codable model to parse JSON. However, a key which was "service_name" was named "name" in the new API. I asked my android developer about how he managed to parse that JSON using the same model. He told me there is support for the same in the GSON library used for parsing in android. The code as below

```
@SerializedName(value = "service_name", alternate = ["name"])
```

I was wondering if this is possible in Codable in a straight forward way. I know this can be achieved through workarounds. But do Swift Codable supports this out of the box

My requirement:

API JSON Response 1

[image: API JSON Response 1]

API 2 JSON Response

[image]

I am using the model as below for parsing

```
// MARK: - CustomerOtherServiceResponseModel
struct CustomerOtherServiceResponseModel:Decodable {
    let name:String
    let externalLink:String?
    let type:ServiceType
}
```

Is it possible to use the same model for both API?. Coding keys can only be mapped to one property right?. Or is there any other way to do the same using the same model.

Comment: yes you can implement a custom CodingKey enum to map key names. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: so should we declare 2 coding keys expecting each values

Comment: If you expect both to be used at the same time you will need a custom `init(from:)` method

Comment: based on api this key changes. but it is mapped to the same variable identity. So, the state of the corresponding view depends on this variable, which expects data from a dynamic key("service_name" or "name")

Comment: I guess the answer to your question then is that Codable doesn't support anything like this out of the box and that you need to write code to handle it. If you want a more meaningful answer I think you need to add more meaningful information to your question and be more explicit in what you are asking.

Comment: I have updated the question so that it can be easily understood.

Comment: Please, next time you post a question always use text and not images for sample data, code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by implementing a custom `init(from:)` where we first try to decode the "name" key and if that doesn't work we try with the "service_name" key.
For the second key we create a new container object using a different CodingKey enum than the one synthesised for us.

```
struct Service: Codable {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let type: String

    enum OtherApiKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "service_name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        if let value = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name) {
            name = value
        } else {
            let otherContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: OtherApiKeys.self)
            name = try otherContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        }
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}
```

Since the json and the struct code you posted didn't match I used my own struct and json here but it should be easy to translate. Below is my test data and code for this

```
let data1 = """
{
    "id": 157,
    "name": "Some name",
    "type": "hair"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let data2 = """
{
    "id": 158,
    "service_name": "Some name",
    "type": "hair"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    for data in [data1, data2] {
        let result = try decoder.decode(Service.self, from: data)
        print(result)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```